# How do i reformat a text file to a new one with a given line width

Tags: python-3.x

How do I reformat a text file to a new one with a given line width?

For example:

**Sample File `input.txt`:**

```
Your program should store a single row of the triangle and calculate each subsequent row by adding a value to the values
immediately above it and to its left. The values on each line must be space-separated.
```

**Sample File `output.txt`:**

```
Your program should store a single row
of the triangle and calculate each
subsequent row by adding a value to the
values immediately above it and to its
left. The values on each line must be
space-separated.
```

**Sample console I/O:**

```
Enter the input filename:
input.txt
Enter the output filename:
output.txt
Enter the line width:
40
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [textwrap.fill](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.fill):

```
import textwrap

text = '''Your program should store a single row of the triangle and calculate each subsequent row by adding a value to the values immediately above it and to its left. The values on each line must be space-separated.'''

print(textwrap.fill(text, 40))
```

yields

```
Your program should store a single row
of the triangle and calculate each
subsequent row by adding a value to the
values immediately above it and to its
left. The values on each line must be
space-separated.
```